# Apache POI - How to draw tables side by side in XWPFDocument

Tags: java, apache-poi, openxml

I am trying to programmatically create a Word document, however when creating two subsequent XWPFTable, the second table gets placed just below the first one.
I would like them to be displayed side-by-side.

I tried reducing the size of the tables so that they could fit half of the page width, but the disposition of the tables did not change.

Is there any way to display them side-by-side?
I suspect this is related to the XMLCursor for the document, but I couldn't find a way to move it properly.

```
XWPFDocument document = new XWPFDocument();

XWPFTable table = document.createTable(3,3);
CTTblWidth width = table.getCTTbl().addNewTblPr().addNewTblW();
width.setType(STTblWidth.PCT);
width.setW(BigInteger.valueOf(2500));
table.getCTTbl().getTblPr().addNewJc().setVal(STJc.LEFT);

XWPFTable table2 = document.createTable(2,2);
CTTblWidth width2 = table2.getCTTbl().addNewTblPr().addNewTblW();
width2.setType(STTblWidth.PCT);
width2.setW(BigInteger.valueOf(2400));

table2.getCTTbl().getTblPr().addNewJc().setVal(STJc.RIGHT);

/* write to OutputStream */
```

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A table is a block-level item, meaning it will take up vertical space according to its height and span to the right margin of the page, whether it uses that space or not. So there is no way to "flow" two tables side-by-side in the same way there is no way to flow two paragraphs side-by-side.

There are a few ways to achieve this effect, but probably the most straight-forward in your case is to create a 1 row by three column table and place your left table inside the first cell and the right-hand table in the third column. The middle column can be used to effect spacing between the two.

You probably don't want any borders on the containing table since it's used for formatting rather than display.

Comment: Thanks @scanny for your answer, however I would think that once fixed the page dimensions height can be found. The workaround of having a single table could definetly work, but I would prefer to keep them separate.

Comment: I think you might be misunderstanding my answer. I'm saying you should *nest* the two tables, side by side, in a "container" table, not combine the two tables into a single one. The container table would be used for layout purposes rather than containing direct content of its own. A table cell can contain a nested table as well as being able to contain paragraphs of text.